# Android Dialog dismiss using handler

Tags: android-dialog

I meet a stranger question,when I read the android GlobalAction source code,I find that it will start a dialog,but it add a judgement which will judge whether this dialog has been shown,if it was shown before,it will be dismissed and then show it.The stranger things is that it dismiss the dialog,than use Handler to send a message to create and show dialog again,I can't understand why it needs to send a handler message,I think it just calls dialog dismiss function.then calls show function,it no problem.The comment said:"Show delayed, so that the dismiss of the previous dialog completes",but I also can't understand the meaning,please someone help me explain it,Thanks a lot.

```
if (mDialog != null) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
            mDialog = null;
            // Show delayed, so that the dismiss of the previous dialog completes
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_SHOW);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Android UI functions are themselves implemented using messages, and so do not complete immediately.  When you call `Dialog.dismiss()`, Android queues a message that does the actual dismissing.  The author of this code wants to ensure the dialog is actually dismissed before showing it again, and so she posts her own message, which will not run until after the one posted by Android.